# How do I integrate the following? $\int{\frac{(1+x^{2})\mathrm dx}{(1-x^{2})\sqrt{1+x^{4}}}}$

Tags: calculus, integration

$$\int{\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x^2)\sqrt{1+x^4}}}\mathrm dx$$

This was a Calc 2 problem for extra credit (we have done hyperbolic trig functions too, if that helps) and I didn't get it (don't think anyone did) -- how would you go about it?

Comment: It's an [elliptic integral](http://dlmf.nist.gov/19), which I don't believe would have been taught in your course...

Comment: So basically you'd say there's no way to integrate it using calc 2 knowledge? That's not a good extra credit...

Comment: @user5157: Are you sure that was the problem? Could it have been a definite integral?

Comment: I am pretty sure, but I will check with others to make sure. So no way to integrate it without some more complex stuff?

Comment: If there is, it's not terribly obvious. Even if you try out a partial fraction decomposition, the three terms are still elliptic integrals (due to the $\sqrt{1+x^4}$ factor).

Comment: Have you seen other integrals in your course that cannot be simplified (in terms of elemetary functions)?   If so, the point of giving this problem may have been to remind you to be on the lookout for them.

Comment: @J.M: It seems like it might not be elliptic after all. See my answer...

Answer (score 63, accepted):

It might not be elliptic after all... (unless I have made some mistake)

$$\int{\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x^2)\sqrt{1+x^4}}}\mathrm dx$$

Let $\displaystyle u = x -\frac{1}{x}$.

Then $\displaystyle du = (1 + \frac{1}{x^2})dx$.

Now $$\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x^2)\sqrt{1+x^4}} = -\frac{x^2(1 + 1/x^2)}{x(x-1/x)\sqrt{x^2(x^2 + 1/x^2)}} = -\frac{1 + 1/x^2}{(x-1/x)\sqrt{(x - 1/x)^2 + 2}}$$

Thus

$$\int{\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x^2)\sqrt{1+x^4}}}\mathrm dx$$

$$= -\int \ \frac{\mathrm{du}}{u \sqrt{u^2 + 2}}$$

Comment: Hah, it is indeed not elliptic! $\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\ln\left(\frac{2x+\sqrt{2x^4+2}}{x^2-1}\right)$ does differentiate to the integrand! Great job; I'm glad I'm wrong!

Comment: Both Maple and Mathematica are not smart enough to do this problem.

Comment: Brilliant, thanks, so this is what we had to see.

Comment: @Moron: Ah, this the standard **C.B.S.E** 12th standard problem.

Comment: @TCL: **Moron** is smart enough, though.

Comment: @TCL: Yeah I know, but since we both are from India, we were aware of this. Thats why I said to him.

Comment: @J.M.: it's $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \ln ( \frac{-2 x+\sqrt{2 x^4+2}}{x^2-1})$. (I got it by asking [Axiom](http://axiom-wiki.newsynthesis.org/FrontPage))

Comment: Hmm, well given how much I’ve come across it, this post confirms it for me: x±1/x is indeed a useful substitution.  I guess it only makes sense, each trig substitution is just that combined with an e^x substitution (excluding tan/tanh/cot/coth)

Answer (score 21):

Somewhat inspired by Moron's wonderful answer, I decided to see if a trigonometric solution would do the job.

Making the substitution $x=\cot\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)$, $\mathrm dx=\frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\cos\;\theta-1}$, we have

$$\int \frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\cos\;\theta(1-\cos\;\theta)\sqrt{1+\cot^4\frac{\theta}{2}}}$$

$$=\int \frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\cos\;\theta(1-\cos\;\theta)\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{1+\cos\;\theta}{1-\cos\;\theta}\right)^2}}$$

$$=\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\int \frac{\mathrm d\theta}{\cos\;\theta\sqrt{1+\cos^2\theta}}$$

which integrates to

$$\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\tanh^{-1}\frac{\sin\;\theta}{\sqrt{1+\cos^2\theta}}$$

Undoing the substitution, we get

$$\frac1{\sqrt{2}}\tanh^{-1}\left(x\sqrt{\frac{2}{x^4+1}}\right)$$

and it is easy to verify that the derivative of this last expression gives the original integrand.

Answer (score 12):

Moron's and J.M.'s solutions are nice.
Hopefully this solution is simpler.

Without loss of generality we may assume that $1\gt x\gt 0$.
Put $x:=\sqrt{y}$, $1\gt y\gt 0$. Then we obtain
$$
\int{\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x^2)\sqrt{1+x^4}}}\mathrm dx=\int{\frac{1+y}{2(1-y)\sqrt{1+y^2}\sqrt{y}}}\mathrm dy.
$$
Introduce the new variable 
$$
t:=\frac{1+y}{1-y},\qquad 1\lt t \lt \infty.
$$
Then we have
$$
y=\frac{-1+t}{1+t},
$$
$$
\mathrm dy=\frac{2}{(1+t)^2}\,\mathrm dt.
$$
Substituting back we obtain
$$
\int{\frac{1+y}{2(1-y)\sqrt{1+y^2}\sqrt{y}}}\mathrm dy=\int{\frac{t}{2\sqrt{1+\left(\dfrac{-1+t}{1+t} \right)^2}\sqrt{\dfrac{-1+t}{1+t}}}\frac{2}{(1+t)^2}\,\mathrm dt}
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\int{\frac{t}{\sqrt{t^4-1}}}\mathrm dt
$$
$$
=\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\ln(t^2+\sqrt{t^4-1})+C.
$$
Putting back everything we obtain
$$
\frac{1}{2\sqrt{2}}\ln\left(\frac{(1+x^2)^2+2\sqrt{2}x\sqrt{1+x^4}}{(1-x^2)^2}\right)+C.
$$

Answer (score 7):

What a surprise! 
Surfing the net, I found an almost same question on
["hard integral"](http://topologicalmusings.wordpress.com/2008/06/27/solution-to-pow-5-a-%E2%80%9Chard%E2%80%9D-integral/)
$$
\displaystyle \int \frac{x^2 - 1}{(x^2 + 1) \sqrt{x^4 + 1}} \, dx
$$
from June 19, 2008.

Comment: That seems to be very similar to my solution! I am not surprised though, after all, this appeared in a test, and I expect it to be well known in some circles. btw, if you liked this problem (which I am guessing you did :-)), you might like this too: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13414/is-this-definite-integral-really-independent-of-a-parameter-how-can-it-be-shown/

Comment: Yes, I like to calculate integrals, although at the first step I check them by computer:-) . I also gave an elementary solution to your referred integral.

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align}\int \frac{(1+x^2)dx}{(1-x^2)\sqrt{x^4+1}}
=&\int \frac{\frac{(1+x^2)dx}{(1-x^2)|1-x^2|}}{\sqrt{\frac{x^4+1}{(1-x^2)^2}}}
=\int \frac{d(\frac x{|1-x^2|})}{\sqrt{1+\frac{2x^2}{(1-x^2)^2}}}
=\frac1{\sqrt2}\sinh^{-1}\frac{\sqrt2 x}{|1-x^2|}
\end{align}

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
& \int\frac{1+x^2}{(1-x^2)\sqrt{1+x^4}}\,dx \\
&= \int\frac{y}{\sqrt{1+\frac{(y-1)^2}{(y+1)^2}}}\cdot\frac{dy}{(y+1)\sqrt{y^2-1}} \tag1\\
&= \frac1{\sqrt2} \int\frac{y}{\sqrt{y^4-1}}\,dy \\
&= \frac1{2\sqrt2} \int\frac{dz}{\sqrt{z^2-1}} \tag2 \\
&= \frac1{2\sqrt2} \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac z{\sqrt{z^2-1}}\right) + C \\
&= \frac1{2\sqrt2} \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{y^2}{\sqrt{y^4-1}}\right) + C \\
&= \frac1{2\sqrt2} \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{\left(\frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2}\right)^2}{\sqrt{\left(\frac{1+x^2}{1-x^2}\right)^4-1}}\right) + C \\
&= \frac1{2\sqrt2} \tanh^{-1}\left(\frac{(1+x^2)^2}{\sqrt{8x^2(1+x^4)}}\right) + C
\end{align*}$$

---

- $(1)$ : substitute $y = \dfrac{1+x^2}{1-x^2} \color{#0000006F}{\iff x=\sqrt{\dfrac{y-1}{y+1}} \implies dx = \dfrac{dy}{(y+1)\sqrt{y^2-1}}}$
- $(2)$ : substitute $z=y^2 \color{#0000006F}{\iff y=\sqrt z \implies dy=\dfrac{dz}{2\sqrt z}}$