# Evaluate $\int \sqrt{1+x^{\frac{3}{2}}} \operatorname d x$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

I can't figure out how to integrate

$$\int \sqrt{1+x^{\frac{3}{2}}} \operatorname d x$$

I've tried substitution by letting $u = x^3$, but it didn't go anywhere. I also tried to integrate using a trigonometric substitution, but that also got me nowhere. Then I tried Wolfram Alpha, and it got me even nowhere-er!

If you could give me a hint as to where to go, I'll try to answer this question at a later time. Thanks!

Comment: @cable What happened to the limits on the integration?

Comment: I took them out of the paragraph...

Comment: Possibly relevant: If you make the substitution $u=\sqrt{x}$ you get an [elliptic integral](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral), and there is [another question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15750/when-is-an-elliptic-integral-expressible-in-terms-of-elementary-functions) on M.SE on when they have closed forms in terms of elementary functions.

Comment: We haven't learned what an elliptic integral is yet. I'm sure, from what you say, I could solve it using that method, but there has to be a way to solve it using other methods. Otherwise, why assign it? :/

Comment: Is it $x^{\frac{3}{2}}$ or is it $\frac{x^3}{2}?$

Comment: @cable729: My point in posting the links is that often integrals just like these don't have closed forms. It's possible your teacher made a typographical error, it's possible your teacher is some kind of sadist that thinks trick questions are a learning experience, and it's also possible (haven't really thought about it much) that there's some substitutions that take us to elementary functions but no one's posted them yet.

Comment: @anon: I doubt this has a simple evaluation. As I noted in the thread you linked to, the "pseudoelliptic" cases tend to occur whenever all the powers of the dummy variable are even within the square root.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The preliminary substitution $x=u^2$ yields the integral

$$2\int u\sqrt{1+u^3}\mathrm du$$

This is indeed in the form of an elliptic integral, where the cubic under the square root factorizes as $(u+1)(u^2-u+1)$.

For handling integrals like these, one first performs a preliminary Möbius substitution. In this case, we let

$$u=-\frac{-1+\sqrt{(-1)^2-(-1)+1}+(-1-\sqrt{(-1)^2-(-1)+1})v}{1+v}=\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{1+v}-(1+\sqrt{3})$$

to give

$$12\int\frac{(1-\sqrt{3}+(1+\sqrt{3})v)}{(1+v)^5}\sqrt{(1-v^2)\left(2\sqrt{3}-3+(2\sqrt{3}+3\right) v^2)}\mathrm dv$$

We can now use the [Jacobian elliptic functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/22). Letting $v=\mathrm{cn}(w|m)$, $\mathrm dv=-\mathrm{sn}(w|m)\mathrm{dn}(w|m)\mathrm dw$ and using the Pythagorean formula $\mathrm{sn}^2(w|m)+\mathrm{cn}^2(w|m)=1$ yields

$$-12\int\frac{(1-\sqrt{3}+(1+\sqrt{3})\mathrm{cn}(w|m))}{(1+\mathrm{cn}(w|m))^5}\sqrt{2\sqrt{3}-3+(2\sqrt{3}+3)\mathrm{cn}^2(w|m)}\mathrm{sn}^2(w|m)\mathrm{dn}(w|m)\mathrm dw$$

We perform a further application of the Pythagorean formula, and factor out a constant:

$$-24\sqrt[4]{3}\int\frac{(1-\sqrt{3}+(1+\sqrt{3})\mathrm{cn}(w|m))}{(1+\mathrm{cn}(w|m))^5}\sqrt{1-\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\mathrm{sn}^2(w|m)}\mathrm{sn}^2(w|m)\mathrm{dn}(w|m)\mathrm dw$$

From that, if we let $m=\dfrac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}$, we can then exploit the identity $\mathrm{dn}^2(w|m)+m\,\mathrm{sn}^2(w|m)=1$:

$$-24\sqrt[4]{3}\int\frac{(1-\sqrt{3}+(1+\sqrt{3})\mathrm{cn}(w|m))}{(1+\mathrm{cn}(w|m))^5}\mathrm{sn}^2(w|m)\mathrm{dn}^2(w|m)\;\mathrm dw$$

We can express everything in terms of $\mathrm{cn}$; using the Pythagorean relations and splitting into partial fractions yields

$$2\sqrt[4]{3}\left(3(5+3\sqrt{3})w-6(13+8\sqrt{3})\varrho_1+48(3+2\sqrt{3})\varrho_2-96(1+\sqrt{3})\varrho_3+48\sqrt{3}\varrho_4\right)$$

where for brevity

$$\varrho_k=\int\frac{\mathrm dw}{(1+\mathrm{cn}(w\mid m))^k}$$

Evaluating $\varrho_k$ is algebraically a rather complicated affair; for brevity, I will instead refer you to formulae 341.52-55 in [Byrd and Friedman](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-65138-0), where a recursion relation is listed. The required members are:

$$\begin{align*}\varrho_1&=w-\varepsilon\left(w \mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)+\frac{\mathrm{sn}\left(w \mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)\mathrm{dn}\left(w \mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)}{1+\mathrm{cn}\left(w \mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)}\\\varrho_2&=\frac13\left((3+\sqrt{3})\varrho_1-\frac12(2+\sqrt{3})w+\frac{\mathrm{sn}\left(w\mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)\mathrm{dn}\left(w\mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)}{\left(1+\mathrm{cn}\left(w\mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)\right)^2}\right)\\\varrho_3&=\frac15\left(2\left(3+\sqrt{3}\right)\varrho_2-\frac32(2+\sqrt{3})\varrho_1+\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}w+\frac{\mathrm{sn}\left(w\mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right) \mathrm{dn}\left(w\mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)}{\left(1+\mathrm{cn}\left(w\mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)\right)^3}\right)\\\varrho_4&=\frac17\left(3\left(3+\sqrt{3}\right)\varrho_3-\frac52\left(2+\sqrt{3}\right)\varrho_2+\frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{2}\varrho_1+\frac{\mathrm{sn}\left(w\mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right) \mathrm{dn}\left(w\mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)}{\left(1+\mathrm{cn}\left(w\mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)\right)^4}\right)\end{align*}$$

where $\varepsilon(w|m)=E(\mathrm{am}(w|m)|m)$ is the [Jacobi epsilon function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/22.16.ii). After much algebra and tears, we end up with

$$\begin{split}\frac{\sqrt[4]{3}}{7} \left((3-\sqrt{3})w-6\,\varepsilon\left(w \mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)+\frac{2\,\mathrm{sn}\left(w\mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right) \mathrm{dn}\left(w\mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)}{\left(1+\mathrm{cn}\left(w\mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)\right)^4}\left(3\mathrm{cn}^3\left(w\mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)+\right.\right. \\ \left.\left.(21+8\sqrt{3})\mathrm{cn}^2\left(w\mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)+(9-8\sqrt{3})\mathrm{cn}\left(w\mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)+8 \sqrt{3}-9\right)\right)\end{split}$$

Undoing the substitutions yields

$$\begin{split}\frac2{7\sqrt[4]{3}}\left(\frac{2\sqrt[4]{3}\sqrt{1+x^{3/2}}(3+x(1+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{x}))}{1+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{x}}-6\sqrt{3} E\left(\arccos\left(\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{1+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{x}}-1\right)\mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)\right. \\ \left.+3(\sqrt{3}-1)F\left(\arccos\left(\frac{2\sqrt{3}}{1+\sqrt{3}+\sqrt{x}}-1\right)\mid \frac{2+\sqrt{3}}{4}\right)\right)\end{split}$$

You can check yourself that the derivative of this expression is $\sqrt{1+x^\frac32}$.

Comment: Holy smoke! That was a nasty homework assignment... ;-)

Comment: Indeed, I'm not at my *Mathematica* computer, so I needed four letter-size sheets and about two hours of writing, me being a slow writer and all... :D at least an explicit elliptic representation is now here for posterity.

Answer (score 9):

Let $I = \int \sqrt{1 + x^{3/2}} \, \mathrm{d} x$. Integrating by parts:
$$
  \begin{eqnarray}
   I &=& x \sqrt{1 + x^{3/2}} - \int x \frac{3}{4} \, \frac{\sqrt{x}}{\sqrt{1+x^{3/2}}} \,  \mathrm{d} x = x \sqrt{1 + x^{3/2}} - \frac{3}{4} \int \sqrt{1+x^{3/2}} \, \mathrm{d} x + \frac{3}{4} \int \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\sqrt{1+x^{3/2}}} \\
  &=& -\frac{3}{4} I + x \sqrt{1 + x^{3/2}}  + \frac{3}{4} \int \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\sqrt{1+x^{3/2}}}
  \end{eqnarray}
$$
Thus 
$$
  I = \frac{4}{7} x \sqrt{1 + x^{3/2}} + \frac{3}{7}  \int \frac{\mathrm{d} x}{\sqrt{1+x^{3/2}}}
$$
The latter integral is not elementary and can be evaluated in terms of Gauss hypergeometric function:
$$
  I = \frac{4}{7} x \sqrt{1 + x^{3/2}} + \frac{3 x}{7} \, {}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2}, \frac{2}{3} ; \frac{5}{3} ; -x^{3/2} \right)
$$

Answer (score 1):

Let's rearrange the integral:

$I=\int \sqrt{1^2+(x^\frac{3}{4})^2} dx$ , and make the substitution $x^\frac{3}{4}=t \Rightarrow \frac{3}{4}x^\frac{-1}{4} dx=dt$ ,

Since $x=t^\frac{4}{3} \Rightarrow dx=\frac{4}{3}t^\frac{1}{3} dt$; if we substitute this into integral we get the following:

$I=\frac{4}{3}\int \sqrt {(1^2+t^2)} t^\frac{1}{3} dt$,

This integral can be solved using [integration by parts](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integration_by_parts) where

$u=t^\frac{1}{3}$ and $dv=\sqrt {1^2+t^2} dt$, and the integral $v=\int\sqrt {1^2+t^2} dt$ can be solved by applying the first formula from this [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_irrational_functions).

Comment: This doesn't exactly lead to anything simpler...

Comment: @HansLundmark,for the last integral one can use substitution $t=\tan{\alpha}$ and identity $1+(\tan{\alpha})^2=(\sec{\alpha})^2$ , in order to make simpler expression...

Comment: @HansLundmark,I have visited your homepage...so you were in Novi Sad last year...that's town where I studied calculus :)

Comment: Dobar dan! It's a small world. :-)  What I meant with my comment was that $3I/4=\int u \, dv = uv - \int v \, du$, and I don't see how to get anywhere with $\int v \, du$, since $v$ will be a fairly complicated expression and $du$ will still involve the cube root of $t$.

Comment: @HansLundmark,after substitution I get $ v=\int\frac{1}{(\cos {\alpha})^3}$d$\alpha$...according to this page  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_integrals_of_trigonometric_functions#Integrands_involving_only_cosine  it should be simpler...

Comment: It's not computing $v$ that's worrying me. It's the integral $\int v \, du$ in the next step that looks hopeless.