# Calculate $\int \frac{r \: dr}{\sqrt{r^4 l^{-2}+ r^2(1 + a^2 l^{-2}) - 2 m r + a^2}}$

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals, elliptic-integrals

How to solve this integral?

$\displaystyle \int \frac{r \: dr}{\sqrt{r^4 l^{-2}+ r^2(1 + a^2 l^{-2}) - 2 m r + a^2}}$

where, $a,l,m \in \mathbb{R}$ and $m > 0$.

I tried putting this in Mathematica for some parameter values, and it gave some complicated function of elliptic integrals.

Comment: Are you trying to find out how to derive the complicated function of elliptic integrals, or are you trying to find a simpler solution? If Mathematica gives you elliptic integrals, it is quite likely there is (with the exception of some specific values of your parameters) no simpler solution.

Comment: I am trying to look for a simpler solution.

Comment: An elliptic integral is what it is, Rahul. An efficient approach for the numerical evaluation of complete elliptic integrals of the first kind is the AGM mean. Also, the parameters $a,l,m$ are pretty irrelevant here.

Comment: Regarding whether there exists an antiderivative in terms of elementary functions, see [When is an elliptic integral expressible in terms of elementary functions?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15750/when-is-an-elliptic-integral-expressible-in-terms-of-elementary-functions). Also, for what it's worth, I spent an entire two weeks at the end of April 2018 playing around with one particular elliptic integral [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/681893/how-to-integrate-int-fracx-sqrtx410x2-96x-71dx).

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro thanks for this. I will look into it.

Answer (score 0):

$$I=\int\frac{rdr}{\sqrt{c_1r^4+c_2r^2+c_3r+c_4}}$$
where:
$c_1=l^{-2}$, $c_2=1+a^2l^{-2}$, $c_3=-2m$ and $c_4=a^2$

This would be my first try but unlike a quadratic, this quartic does not seem to have a general solution