# Why is it impossible to solve an elliptic integral analytically?

Tags: calculus

Whenever you try to find the "circumference" of an ellipse you end up with an integral that looks like this:
$$4a\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-e^2\sin^2{\theta}} d\theta, $$
I know that there isn't an analytical solution to this because I've been told so, but how does one go abiut proving that statement?

Comment: Usually Liouville's theorem is used. It's well known that this particular integral does not have an elementary solution.

Comment: You may be interested in this paper: http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/papers/elemint.pdf

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/155/how-can-you-prove-that-a-function-has-no-closed-form-integral and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15750/when-is-an-elliptic-integral-expressible-in-terms-of-elementary-functions