# Resources for learning Elliptic Integrals

Tags: calculus, special-functions

During a quiz my Calc 3 professor made a typo.  He corrected it in class, but he offered a challenge to anyone who could solve the integral.

The (original) question was:

Find the length of the curve as described by the vector valued function $\vec{r} = \frac{1}{3}t^{3}\vec{i} + t^{2}\vec{j} + 4t\vec{k} $ where $0 \le t \le 3$

This give us:

$\int_0^3 \! \sqrt{t^{4}+4t^{2}+16} \, \mathrm{d}t$

Wolfram Alpha says that the solution to this involves Incomplete Elliptic Integrals of the First and Second Kinds.  I was wondering if anyone had any level appropriate resources where I can find information about how to attack integrals like this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

(might as well...)

As a quick review: anytime you see an integral that involves the square root of a cubic or a quartic polynomial, it is quite likely that an elliptic integral will be needed (except in [some very](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15719) [special cases](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15750), termed "pseudoelliptic integrals").

Now, for the integral at hand (treating the indefinite case for now, and worrying about the limits later): your integrand is a quartic that consists of only *even* powers of the dummy variable, so the first thing to do is to perform a (modified) Weierstrass substitution, $t=2\tan\dfrac{u}{2}$:

$$\begin{align*}
\int \sqrt{t^4+4t^2+16} \,\mathrm dt&=8\int \frac{\sqrt{3+\cos^2 u}}{(1+\cos\,u)^2} \mathrm du=8\int \frac{\sqrt{4-\sin^2 u}}{(1+\cos\,u)^2} \mathrm du\\
&=16\int \frac{\sqrt{1-\frac14 \sin^2 u}}{(1+\cos\,u)^2} \mathrm du
\end{align*}$$

(the additional factor of $2$ in the substitution used comes from the fourth root of the polynomial's constant term.)

Why did I make those last few transformations, you ask? This is because the standard elliptic integrals are made to pop out easily when the part within the square root takes the form $\sqrt{1-m\,\sin^2 u}$.

In any event, we now need to perform a Jacobian substitution. We let $u=\mathrm{am}(v\mid m)$, where $\mathrm{am}$ is the [Jacobian amplitude function](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/JacobiAmplitude.html) and $m$ is a constant (in elliptic integral parlance, the *parameter*) to be determined. The usual [Jacobian elliptic functions](http://dlmf.nist.gov/22) come from this basic function:

$$\begin{align*}
\mathrm{sn}(v\mid m)&=\sin(\mathrm{am}(v\mid m))\\
\mathrm{cn}(v\mid m)&=\cos(\mathrm{am}(v\mid m))\\
\mathrm{dn}(v\mid m)&=\frac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dv}\mathrm{am}(v\mid m)=\sqrt{1-m\,\sin^2(\mathrm{am}(v\mid m))}
\end{align*}$$

Consideration of the last relation involving $\mathrm{dn}$ indicates that we can choose $m=\frac14$ for convenience; thus,

$$16\int \frac{\sqrt{1-\frac14 \sin^2 u}}{(1+\cos\,u)^2} \mathrm du=16\int \frac{\mathrm{dn}^2\left(v\mid\frac14\right)}{\left(1+\mathrm{cn}\left(v\mid\frac14\right)\right)^2} \mathrm dv=4\int \frac{3+\mathrm{cn}^2\left(v\mid\frac14\right)}{\left(1+\mathrm{cn}\left(v\mid\frac14\right)\right)^2} \mathrm dv$$

Unfortunately, things get rather messy at this juncture, so I had to ask for some assistance from *Mathematica*. A little bit of massaging of the results from *Mathematica* yielded

$$4\int \frac{3+\mathrm{cn}^2\left(v\mid\frac14\right)}{\left(1+\mathrm{cn}\left(v\mid\frac14\right)\right)^2} \mathrm dv=\frac23\left(6v-4\,\varepsilon\left(v \mid \frac14\right)+\frac{4\left(3+\mathrm{cn}\left(v\mid \frac14\right)\right)\mathrm{dn}\left(v\mid \frac14\right)\mathrm{sn}\left(v\mid \frac14\right)}{\left(1+\mathrm{cn}\left(v\mid \frac14\right)\right)^2}\right)$$

where $\varepsilon(v\mid m)$ is the [Jacobi epsilon function](http://dlmf.nist.gov/22.16.ii).

One could of course use the appropriate formulae from [Byrd and Friedman's *Handbook of Elliptic Integrals for Engineers and Scientists*](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/978-3-642-65138-0) if one insists on a wholly manual evaluation, but the evaluation involves a rather messy set of recurrence relations. (If I find more time, I'll eventually edit this answer to include the full solution, bloody guts and all...)

In any event, to now consider the *definite* integral, we undo the two substitutions in turn and apply those to the limits of the original integral. In particular, the inverse of $\phi=\mathrm{am}(v\mid m)$ is the incomplete elliptic integral of the first kind, $v=F(\phi\mid m)$, while the Jacobi epsilon function satisfies the relation

$\varepsilon(F(\phi\mid m)\mid m)=E(\phi\mid m)$

where $E(\phi\mid m)$ is the incomplete elliptic integral of the second kind. The transformed limits are then $v=0$ and $v=F\left(2\arctan\frac32\mid\frac14\right)$

We finally end up with

$$\int_0^3 \sqrt{t^4+4t^2+16} \,\mathrm dt=\frac{17}{13}\sqrt{133}+4\,F\left(2\arctan\frac32\mid\frac14\right)-\frac83 \,E\left(2\arctan\frac32\mid\frac14\right)$$

which is a fair bit simpler than what you get if you directly input the integral into *Mathematica*.

---

If it wasn't already apparent in the paragraphs above: elliptic integrals and elliptic functions are very different things; one is (very roughly) the inverse of the other. Too many people tend to conflate these two families of functions, though they are definitely related...

In addition to Byrd/Friedman, you'll also want to look into [Greenhill's *The Applications of Elliptic Functions*](http://archive.org/details/applicationselli00greerich), which, contrary to the title, also deals a bit with the elliptic integrals as well.

Comment: Shit man... This is a lot to digest, thank you so much.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, what course would you learn how to do all that?

Comment: Most likely during a special topics course on special functions.  There's not much of a reason for it to be taught within the curriculum normally.  If you're going to a university currently I would suggest speaking with a professor about it, they might be interested in holding a class like that, especially if you can demonstrate interest.

Comment: ...actually in my case, I am mostly self-taught with respect to knowledge of special functions. My long-ago bachelor's degree certainly did not talk about them.

Answer (score 5):

There are plenty of places to look (for example, most any older 2-semester advanced undergraduate "mathematics for physicists" or "mathematics for engineers" text), but given that you're in Calculus III, some of these might be too advanced. If you can find a copy (your college library may have a copy, or might be able to get a copy using interlibrary loan), I strongly recommend the treatment of elliptic integrals at the end of G. M. Fichtenholz's book **The Indefinite Integral** (translated to English by Richard A. Silverman in 1971). Also, the books below might be useful, but Fichtenholz's book would be much better suited for you, I think. (I happen to have a copy of Fichtenholz's book and Bowman's book, by the way.)

Arthur Latham Baker, **Elliptic functions: An Elementary Text-book for Students of Mathematics** (1906) http://books.google.com/books?id=EjYaAAAAYAAJ

Alfred Cardew Dixon, **The Elementary Properties of the Elliptic Functions With Examples** (1894) http://books.google.com/books?id=Gx4SAAAAYAAJ

Frank Bowman, **Introduction to Elliptic Functions With Applications** (reprinted by Dover Publications in 1961)