# Integrate square root of 4th grad polynomials

Tags: calculus, integration, special-functions

During some calculations for a program I came upon this Integral which I am not able to solve.
I already tried Matlab but it didn't help me.
Here is the Integral:
$$\int\left(\sqrt{\sum_{0}^{5} 9 a_i^2 t^4 +12 a_i b_i t^3 + 6 a_i c_i t^2 + 4 b_i^2 t^2 + 4 b_i c_i t +c_i^2}\right) dt$$

I already found [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/111921/resources-for-learning-elliptic-integrals) but couldn't solve my problem.

Thanks in advance

Edit: Rearranging the formula
$$\int\left(\sqrt{\sum_{0}^{5} (3 a_i t^2 + c_i)^2 + 4 b_i t^2 (3 a_i t + b_i) + 4 b_i c_i t}\right) dt$$

Comment: You could notice that $9a_i^2t^4+6a_ic_it^2+c_i^2=(3a_it^2+c_i)^2$ and $12a_ib_it^3+b_i^2t=(3a_it^2+b_i)4b_it$  The similarity in the forms in parentheses makes me wonder if that could be helpful.  Maybe there is something in how this came about that is telling you.

Comment: note that theres a bunch of integrals of polynomials in square roots that are not explicitly solvable [Elliptic Integrals](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic_integral).

Comment: There is no $b_i^2 t$ but I could write $12 a_i b_i t^3 + 4 b_i^2 t^2$ as $4 b_i t^2 (3 a_i t + b_i)$. I didn't notice the other one at first sight though... That might come in handy.

Comment: Your edited formula is not consistent with the first one.

Comment: Thanks, had a typo in there. Should be correct now.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with this formula
$$\sum\left(u\left(15 c_i^2 \sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{- a_i^2 b_i^2 (c_i^2 -1)}-6a_i^2 b_i^2 u^{3/2} - a_i b_i}{\sqrt{-a_i^2 b_i^2(c_i^2-1)}-a_i b_i}}
\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{-a_i^2 b_i^2(c_i^2-1)}+6 a_i^2 b_i^2 u^{3/2}+a_i b_i}{\sqrt{-a_i^2 b_i^2(c_i^2 -1)}+a_i b_i}}\\
F_1\left(\frac{2}{3};\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2};\frac{5}{3};-\frac{6 a_i^2 b_i^2 u^{3/2}}{a_i b_i + \sqrt{- a_i^2 b_i^2(c_i^2 -1)}},-\frac{6 a_i^2 b_i^2 u^{3/2}}{a_i b_i - \sqrt{-a_i^2 b_i^2 - (c_i^2 -1)}}\right)+36 a_i b_i u^{3/2}\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{- a_i^2 b_i^2(c_i^2 -1)}-6 a_i^2 b_i^2 u^{3/2}- a_i b_i}{\sqrt{-a_i^2 b_i^2(c_i^2 -1)}-a_i b_i}}\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{- a_i^2 b_i^2(c_i^2 -1)}+6 a_i^2 b_i^2 u^{3/2}+a_i b_i}{\sqrt{-a_i^2 b_i^2(c_i^2 -1)}-a_i b_i}}\\
F_1\left(\frac{5}{3};\frac{1}{2};\frac{1}{2};\frac{8}{3};-\frac{6 a_i^2 b_i^2 u^{3/2}}{a_i b_i+\sqrt{- a_i^2 b_i^2(c_i^2-1)}},-\frac{6 a_i^2 b_i^2 u^{3/2}}{a_i b_i -\sqrt{- a_i^2 b_i^2(c_i^2-1)}}\right)\\
+10(12 a_i b_i u^{3/2}(3 a_i b_i u^{3/2}+1)+c_i^2)\right)\right)
/\left(25 \sqrt{12 a_i b_i u^{3/2}(3 a_i b_i u^{3/2}+1)+c_i^2}\right)
(+ constant)$$

Were $F_1$ is the Appell hypergeometric function and $u=t^2$.

Could that be right or are there any errors (probably...)?