# Can it possible to calculate this integral directly, probably concerning ellipti integral

Tags: calculus, integration, elliptic-integrals

A student asked me to help her calculating this problem: Assume the length $L$ of a curve is given, and the equation of the curve is
\begin{gather*}
y(x)=A \sin\Big(\pi x-\frac{\pi}{2}\Big), 0\leq x\leq 1,
\end{gather*}
calculate the amplitude $A$, where $A\in\mathbb{R}$, actualy you can assume that $A$ is a positive real number. Here is my incomplete solution:

$\because y=-A\cos(\pi x), y'(x)=\pi A \sin (\pi x)=k\sin(\pi x), \text{ where } k=\pi A, $
therefore, 
\begin{align*}
L&=\int_0^1\sqrt{1+(y'(x))^2} dx=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^1\sqrt{1+k^2\sin^2(\pi x)}d(\pi x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\sqrt{1+k^2\sin^2(s)}ds\\
&=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1+k^2\sin^2(s)}ds=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^1\frac{\sqrt{1+k^2 t^2}}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}dt, \quad (\sin s=t).
\end{align*}

Then I do not know how to proceed, because I know the last integral is the complete Ellptic Integral EllipticE($\sqrt{-\pi^2A^2}$), as indicated in  Maple 16.

After using Maple, I found that it is very difficult to solve for $A$ through equation
\begin{gather*}
EllipticE(\sqrt{-\pi^2A^2})=\pi L/2.
\end{gather*}
But after I searched this website, I found the thread [How do I integrate the following?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/15719/how-do-i-integrate-the-following-int-frac1x2-mathrm-dx1-x2-sqr). Then I was very doubt that the result of Maple. Can it be possible to calculate the $A$ from 
the length $L$ analytically, or is it possible to evaluate the integral $\int_0^1\sqrt{1+\pi^2A^2\sin^2(\pi x)}dx$ directly, without the help of Elliptic Integral?

Comment: I may see how to do the indefinite integral, but it's going to be messy...

Comment: I'm confused. Isn't the curve $(x,y(x)) = (x, A \sin(\pi x - n/2))$? So its length would involve an integral of cos, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me try this from your last step.

$$t=\frac{\tan\theta}k,dt=\frac{\sec^2\theta d\theta}{k}$$
$$\frac2\pi\int\limits_0^1\frac{\sqrt{1+k^2 t^2}}{1-t^2}dt=\frac2\pi\int\limits_0^{\tan^{-1}k}\frac{\frac{\sec^2\theta}k\sqrt{1+\tan^2\theta}d\theta}{1-\frac{\tan^2\theta}{k^2}}=$$
$$\frac{2k}\pi\int\limits_0^{\tan^{-1}k}\frac{\sec^3\theta d\theta}{k^2-\tan^2\theta}=2A\int\limits_0^{\tan^{-1}k}\frac{\cos\theta d\theta}{\cos^2\theta(k^2\cos^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)}=$$
$$2A\int\limits_0^{\tan^{-1}k}\frac{\cos\theta d\theta}{(1-\sin^2\theta)(k^2-k^2\sin^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)}$$
Partial fractions time.

$$u=\sin\theta,du=\cos\theta d\theta$$
$$2A\int\limits_0^{\tan^{-1}k}\frac{\cos\theta d\theta}{(1-\sin^2\theta)(k^2-k^2\sin^2\theta-\sin^2\theta)}=$$
$$2A\int\limits_1^\frac1{\sqrt{k^2+1}}\frac{du}{(1-u)(1+u)(k-u\sqrt{k^2+1})(k+u\sqrt{k^2+1})}$$

If I've done everything right so far, this should lead to an answer.  I may work this further later to make sure I get a matching answer.

Comment: Mike, I am very sorry for my mistyping in the integrand of the  last integral, it should be $\frac{sqrt{1+k^2 t^2}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}$.

Comment: If there was an elementary antiderivative, I'm sure Maple or Mathematica would find it. I'm pretty sure there isn't one.

Comment: Yeah, I just noticed that wouldn't come out right.  That 1 as the lower limit was going to be a problem.