# What substitution should I do to solve the following integral?

Tags: calculus, integration

Evaluate $$ \int{\frac{(1+x^2)}{(1-x^2)\sqrt{1+x^2+x^4}}}dx              $$
I substituted $x- \frac{1}{x}  $ with u so $$-\int{\frac{du}{u\sqrt{u^2+3}}} $$
Now I put $u=\frac1t$
so $$\int{\frac{dt}{\sqrt{1+3t^2}}}   $$

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/692118/integrate-fracx2-1x21-frac1-sqrt1x4dx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

HINT:

$$\text{Set }\int\left(1+\dfrac1{x^2}\right)dx=u\text{ so that }\dfrac{du}{dx}=\cdots$$

$$\text{in }\frac{(1+x^2)}{(1-x^2)\sqrt{1+x^2+x^4}}=\dfrac{1+\dfrac1{x^2}}{\left(x-\dfrac1x\right)\sqrt{\dfrac1{x^2}+1+x^2}}$$
and use
$$\dfrac1{x^2}+x^2=\left(x-\dfrac1x\right)^2+2$$

For $\int\dfrac{du}{u\sqrt{u^2+3}}$

either set $u=\sqrt3\tan y$

or for $\int\dfrac{du}{u\sqrt{u^2+3}}=\int\dfrac{u\ du}{u^2\sqrt{u^2+3}}$
set $\sqrt{u^2+3}=v$

Comment: Yes I reached upto this step. I tried proceeding by making substitution $ u= \frac{1}{t} $. Can you help me on that ?

Comment: @arutoregni, Can you please update your answer with your method. Btw, I've suggested two other substitutions, right?