# Show an integral is independent of a parameter

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, contour-integration

Apologies in advance for the large number of parameters. I have run into the integral
$$
\frac{\zeta + \eta}{\rho^{2}}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\omega^2q^2}{\left[\,\omega^{2} - \left(\lambda + 2\mu\right)q^{2}/\rho\,\right]^{\, 2} + \left[\,\left(\zeta + \eta\right)\omega q^{2}/\rho\,\right]^{\, 2}}\,
\mathrm{d}\omega
$$
where $\omega, q, \zeta, \eta, \rho \in 
 \mathbb{R}$ and $\lambda, \mu \in \mathbb{C}$.

With some difficulty, I was able to perform the integral and the result is $$\frac{\pi}{2\rho},$$ which wasn't apparent until the final step in my derivation. Notably for me, it is $q$-independent.

Is there a clever substitution that makes it clear that this is $q$-independent? (and $\zeta,\eta,\lambda,\mu$-independent). If the result of a definite integral is independent of a parameter, is it *always* possible to find a substitution that renders the integrand independent of that parameter? (I am not sure if this question is sensible).

Comment: Interesting question ! But as far as I know it is good practice to ask in one post one question, and create other posts for related questions

Comment: Thanks for the tip! I have pared down the questions.

Comment: What happens when $q=0$?  Anyway, you can reduce the number of parameters since $\lambda,\mu$ only appears as $\lambda'=\lambda+2\mu$ and $\zeta,\eta$ only appears as $\zeta'=\zeta+\eta$, so you want to show
$$
\frac{\zeta'}{\rho}\int_0^{\infty}\frac{\omega^2q^2}{(\omega^2 - \lambda'q^2/\rho)^2 + (\zeta'\omega q^2/\rho)^2}\,
\mathrm{d}\omega=2\pi.
$$which looks similar to [this previous question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13414).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found a satisfactory way to convince myself of this. First, note the integrand only depends on $\omega^2$ so I can integrate over the real line and take half. Define
$$a^2\equiv \frac{\left(\lambda+2\mu\right)q^2}{\rho},\;\;b\equiv\frac{\left(\zeta+\eta\right)q^2}{\rho}.$$ The integral becomes $$\frac{b}{2\rho}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\omega^2}{\left(\omega^2-a^2\right)^2+\left(b\omega\right)^2}\mathrm{d}\omega.$$ Substitute $$\omega'=\frac{\omega}{b}$$ to find the integral is equal to $$\frac{1}{2\rho}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\frac{\omega'^2}{\left(\omega'^2-\frac{a^2}{b^2}\right)^2+\omega'^2}\mathrm{d}\omega'.$$ I came up with this substitution by guessing it'd be a scaling by some power of $b$ and matching powers so that it factors out of the denominator. To see the integral is independent of $a^2/b^2$ is equivalent to [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/13414/is-this-definite-integral-really-independent-of-a-parameter-how-can-it-be-shown).